# LAG aggregation problems

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose that I have  a table with the following columns.

```
yr      mo     group    players
```

yr is the year in four digits 20xx, month is a two digit month, group is a unique group identifier - numeric and players is the number of players for a given year month.

I am trying - and failing - to write a query that for each month outputs the following:

- the number of groups in the current period,
- the number of groups in the period one year back,
- the difference in number of groups

AND (here is the part that I am really stuck at)
looks that the groups in the current period - pairs them up with the groups that have the same id's and figures out the net difference in players.

As a basic example if there were groups 1,2,3 with players 3,4,5 respectively in 1,2014 and groups 1,2 with players 2,3 in 1, 2015 then the difference in players would be -2 and the difference in groups would be 1.

Comment: how would the difference in players be -2 when 2014 had 12 players and 2015 had 5 players? Or are those player numbers, but then how are you calculating it still? How come both players and groups decreased in 2015, but the difference in players is negative while the difference in groups is positive?  Could you show some example data in your table and your desired results with a little more clarification around the calculations? I get the feeling like a self join on pre-aggregated subqueries might be a better fit than lag or some other window function.

Comment: I was thinking self join but I was having a bit of a problem with that. The difference is -2 as there are groups 1,2 that exist in both time periods. So it is the sum of players in groups 1,2 for 1,2015 (5) minus the sum of players in groups 1,2 for 1,2014 (7).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT p2.grp) as grp_current_period,
  COUNT(DISTINCT p1.grp) AS grp_last_year,
  COUNT(DISTINCT p2.grp) - COUNT(DISTINCT p1.grp) AS grp_diff,
  SUM(CASE WHEN p1.grp IS NULL THEN 0 
      ELSE SUM(p2.players - p1.players) 
  END) as players_diff
FROM 
  myTable p2 LEFT JOIN 
  myTable p1 ON p2.mo = p1.mo AND 
                p2.yr = p1.yr - 1 AND
                p2.grp = p1.grp
GROUP BY p2.yr, p2.mo
```

Here I am joining the current month/year to previous year and if team did not exist player difference is set to zero.